# ASP.NET - load more than two

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I want to load from my db all photos for that product which meets the condition > 2.

[image]

When PCProductID has got one record in PCPhotoID i want to add single image but when it repeat itself e.g. PCProductID == 2 has got two records PCPhotoID, I want them to load in slider.

I don't know how to write correct condition.

```
<div class="row images">
            @foreach (var item in Model.PCPhotos)
            {

                if (Model.PCProduct.PCProductID == item.PCProductID)
                {

                    <img src="~/Content/PCProduct/@item.IconFileName" />

                }
            }
        </div>
```

ProductViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<PCPhoto> PCPhotos { get; set; }
public PCProduct PCProduct { get; set; }
```

StoreController:

```
public ActionResult PCDetails(int id)
        {
        var pcproduct = db.PCProducts.Find(id);
        var producer = db.Producers.ToList();
        var networkcard = db.NetworkCards.ToList();
        var soundcard = db.SoundCards.ToList();
        var computercase = db.ComputerCases.ToList();
        var ram = db.RAMs.ToList();
        var graphic = db.Graphics.ToList();
        var cpu = db.CPUs.ToList();
        var motherboard = db.Motherboards.ToList();
        var pcphotos = db.PCPhotos.ToList();

        var vm = new ProductViewModel
        {
            PCProduct = pcproduct,
            Producer = producer,
            NetworkCards = networkcard,
            SoundCards = soundcard,
            ComputerCases = computercase,
            RAMs = ram,
            Graphics = graphic,
            CPUs = cpu,
            Motherboards = motherboard,
            PCPhotos = pcphotos
        };


        return View(vm);
        }
```

class PCProduct:

```
    public class PCProduct
    {
         public int PCProductID { get; set; }

         public ICollection<PCPhoto> PCPhotos { get; set; }
          // More stuff and fks added
     }
```

class PCPhoto:

```
public class PCPhoto
    {
        public int PCPhotoID { get; set; }
        public int PCProductID { get; set; }

        public string IconFileName { get; set; }

        public PCProduct PCProduct { get; set; }

    }
```

Edited: I need on my pcproduct view more data from other tables, like information about CPU, motherboard etc. Is there any way to do this?

**PS.** Your code worked but pcphotos.count() == 1 was skipped only second contidion worked but shows all photos even that first single image too

Comment: "which meets the condition > 2.". Which of the two ID columns should be > 2? It's not completely clear from your wording. And what slider are you using? Do you understand the HTML format the slider would require to load things into it? It's not clear what exactly your problem is. You've stated some aims, but not made clear why you're struggling to achieve them (other than, for instance, simple lack of time spent researching and coding).

Comment: Look on table, each PCProductID repeat itself but only PCProductID == 1 has got only one record (one photo path). When it's not repeating itself i want to load single <img> in otherwise i want to create slider e.g. PCProductID == 5 has got 5 records which meens 5 image slider

Comment: I don't have there slider, i don't need it for now. I only need to display correct condition. Photos > 2 display them on div else load single image. That's simple

Comment: You need to show your model code. Does the PCPhoto object contain a list of PcProducts with which it is associated? If so then you can just check the length of that list

Comment: That's the point i know that i must check length but i don't know how. Edited code for ya

Comment: Since I asked about the PcPhoto object specifically, it would help a lot if you showed that too. Two separate lists like that doesn't reflect the reality of your data structure, it would seem. Since you're using Entity Framework, if you defined your database relationships properly, it should have created the entity to contain a list of objects with foreign keys to to it

Comment: yeah, i'm editing one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your model and database, it's clear each Product can be associated with one or more Photos, and that this is represented through your entity classes.

The Product object in your viewmodel will already contain the associated photos - Entity Framework will populate them for you based on your foreign keys. If there's more than one photo, use a slider. If not, don't:

View:

```
@Model ProductViewModel

<div class="productid">Product ID: @Model.PCProduct.PcProductID</div>
<div class="row images">
   @if (Model.PCProduct.PCPhotos.Count() == 1) {
     <img src="~/Content/PCProduct/@Model.PCProduct.PCPhotos.ElementAt(0).IconFileName" />
   }
   else if (Model.PCProduct.PCPhotos.Count() > 1)
   {
      //here you create the HTML for the slider. You may need a foreach to loop through Model.PCPhotos and make some HTML or JSON for each one, depends on what the slider plugin requires.
   }
</div>
```

The viewmodel you were using, with two separate lists, completely disassociated the photos from the products, and thus made it difficult/impossible to make the connections you needed between the data items. Instead you can take advantage of the structure already available to you, as per this example. You don't need a separate ViewModel object at all for this task.

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Comment: Can you try `Model.PCPhotos.Count()` instead? Sometimes memory fails me :-)

Comment: I will try tommorow and i will write :) thanks for now

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<PCPhoto>'

Comment: I worked a little yesterday and now it's complicated... I must display more information on this view, so i need diffrent viewmodel i edited code

Comment: Ok but the same principle still applies. You still have to look at the photos linked to with the specific Product. Even if the product is now just a part of the view model, you just do `@if (Model.PCProduct.PCPhotos.Count() == 1) {` instead. There's no change to the code for displaying the photos. And I'm guessing that these other objects (network cards etc) are all supposed to be part of the PCProduct too? So if you're adding them to the viewmodel in the way you've shown, then you're committing the same logical error which gave you problems with the photos, and the correction is the same too

Comment: You are great! Many many thanks it works now ! u can edit code and i will apply

Comment: Ok I have changed it to reflect using the ProductViewModel. Don't forget to "accept" the answer as well if it helped you. Thanks :-)

Comment: I added those objects to viewmodel only for information (pcproduct has got network card with name lan wan etc. So i nedded other table with informations about only network cards and i habe other view to network cards too :) ) i’m almost at the end of my app and all works good only that one if i wasnt abble to write :) thank you one more time